# Elegant Dynamic Type Casting

Tags: c#

I'd appreciate your advice on the following:

I'm using polymorphism. I have a base class and 30 sub classes that inherit this base class. I'm up casting instances of these sub classes to the base class type so that they can be handled in a more generic fashion.

My question is this.
I need to access a public property that is specific to a particular sub class. Do I need to write a giant case statement where I check the type and down cast accordingly in order to access the property I need or is there a more elegant solution?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        animal slyvester = new cat();
        animal lassie = new dog();
        animal silver = new horse();

        //  Big ugly type checking code. If I have 30 types to check is there a better way?
        if (slyvester.GetType() == typeof(cat)) {
            Console.WriteLine(((cat)(animal)slyvester).PurrStrength);
        }
        else if(slyvester.GetType() == typeof(dog)) {

        }
        else if (slyvester.GetType() == typeof(horse))
        {

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class animal { 

}

public class cat : animal {

    private string _purrStrength = "Teeth Shattering";

    public string PurrStrength {
        get { return _purrStrength; }
        set { _purrStrength = value; }
    }

}

public class dog : animal { 

}

public class horse : animal { 

}
```

Comment: The question is: are you sure in a moment of query which type is it?

Comment: does each animal have a specific property that you want to read, or just cat? In other words, what happens in the `else if(slyvester.GetType() == typeof(dog))` ?

Comment: The real question is, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. To answer the first question no I'm not sure of the type at the moment of query. To answer the second question the property is specific to cat which is why I haven't implemented it in the base class. if(slyvester.GetType() == typeof(dog)) I return nothing.

Comment: but do dogs have also their specific properties? Otherwise you only really need `if (slyvester.GetType() == typeof(cat))` and not all the other else if blocks

Comment: I've added a simple example here to understand the concept. The actual code is more complex. What I am trying to achieve is this. I am writing a wizard using WPF. The wizard returns a Chart object. The Chart class has 30 sub classes e.g. ChartBar, ChartPie etc. I want the user to select the chart type in step 1 of the wizard. Therefore wizards underlying data context is an object of type Chart that could be the generic representation (up casted representation) of any of the 30 sub types. In subsequent wizard steps e.g. Step 2 I need to access properties particular to the underlying type.

Comment: Yes Paolo you are right about not needing the other else if blocks. I guess the issue is that certain properties are common to many of the charts but not all. For example 25 of the 30 chart types might have a property "XAxis". So whilst I might not need to check every type I have to check all types that are relevant which is not very elegant. Doesn't look like there's any other way of doing it though. I guess I'll just abstract out the ugly huge type checking method as much as possible so the code isn't too boiler plate.

Comment: you can use reflection, like @pinusnegra suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to know the exact type of the passed object, you just need a property value in case it doesn't exist in the base type, but it may or may not exists in the actual type, you can use reflection:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            animal slyvester = new cat();
            animal lassie = new dog();
            animal silver = new horse();

            DoSomething(slyvester);
            DoSomething(lassie);
            DoSomething(silver);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DoSomething(animal entity)
        {
            string INeedThisProperty = "PurrStrength";
            Type type = entity.GetType();
            PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(INeedThisProperty);

            if (property != null && property.CanRead)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", property.GetValue(entity, null));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. There are many valid and interesting responses here. I don't want to implement the property in the base class (or interface as others have suggested) because that property is not implemented by all of the subclasses therefore that violates the base class (or interface) abstraction does it not? Therefore I think the reflection option will probably work best for me. Thanks again!

Comment: my experience is that using reflection for this type of problems will bite you back sooner or later. :-S

Comment: @vidstige It's a very simplified example, I think. It would not be the best choice for a common problem, but I found it very useful in some edge cases. For example logging and adapters (duck typing). But you are right, it can result in low performance and equivocal code. But it has it's place.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider an interface based approach. With interfaces, you define a set of operations (a contract by which implementers must conform) which your types must define. E.g, we could define a base interface, `IAnimal`

```
public interface IAnimal
{
  string GetSound();
}
```

From which we can define some animal types:

```
public class Cat : IAnimal
{
  public string GetSound()
  {
    return "Meow!";
  }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
  public string GetSound()
  {
    return "Woof!";
  }
}
```

Now, when we want to declare our animal, we declare it of type `IAnimal`:

```
IAnimal cat = new Cat();
IAnimal dog = new Dog();

Console.WriteLine(cat.GetSound());
Console.WriteLine(dog.GetSound());
```

You could go one step further, and specialise your animals:

```
public class Cat : IAnimal
{
  public virtual string GetSound()
  {
    return "Meow!";
  }
}

public class BigCat : Cat
{
  public override string GetSound()
  {
    return "Roar!";
  }
}
```

In the latter example, I can make a default implementation of the cat's `GetSound` method, and then override it for my big cat.

Interface based programming hides away the need to horrible type conversions, because an interface guarantees a set of operations that will be provided.

Answer (score 0):

If in precise moment of property access you dont't have any clue what type is it, somehow you have to figure out it.

Or, what I personaly would do, is try to create virtual functions/properties on base class that describes my child classes action in more generic way, override them in child classes with concrete implementation and after call that functions/properties using upper casted objects.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). The idea is to introduce a method in the base interface or as in this case the base class. Then just call this method! The runtime will automagically delegate the call to the correct type.

Look at the modified implementation below:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract void OutputInterestingFact();
}

public class Cat : Animal {

    private string _purrStrength = "Teeth Shattering";

    public string PurrStrength {
        get { return _purrStrength; }
        set { _purrStrength = value; }
    }

    public override void OutputInterestingFact()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(PurrStrength);
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    public override void OutputInterestingFact()
    {
        // Do stuff for dog here
    }
}

public class Horse : Animal {
    public override void OutputInterestingFact()
    {
        // Do stuff for horse here
    }
}
```

I made the Animal into an abstract class. You could also make the `OutputInterestingFact` method virtual with an empty method body.

I've also renamed your classes to begin with an upper case letter. Make this a habit since this is practice in C# and other programmers will find your code easier to read.

Now, to use this just call the method.

```
slyvester.OutputInterestingFact();
```

Is that elegant enough?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not cover all the cases that I can think of, but just 2 possible solutions:

```
class Animal {
    public abstract string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

class Cat : Animal {
    public override string PropertyValue {
        get { return PurrStrength; }
        set { PurrStrength = value; }
    }
}
```

or, for multiple properties:

```
class Animal {
    public virtual string[] GetPropertyValues() { return null; }
}

class Cat : Animal {
    public override string[] GetPropertyValues() {
        return new string[] { PurrStrength };
    }
}
```