# Optimize multiple types casting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, casting

I have multiple types of combo boxes calling this event OnFilterChanged, and i was wondering if there is an better way to do the casting in fewer lines.

```
private void filtro_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int f = -1;
            ComboBox cb;
            ToolStripComboBox tscb;

            if (sender.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
            {
                cb = (ComboBox)sender;
                f = cb.SelectedIndex;
            }
            else if (sender.GetType() == typeof(ToolStripComboBox))
            {
                tscb = (ToolStripComboBox)sender;
                f = tscb.SelectedIndex;  
            }
            setFiltro(f);
        }

}
```

Thanks;

ps.: Im looking for a better way than its shown on:
[Elegant Dynamic Type Casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118380/elegant-dynamic-type-casting)

Comment: I would question why you are getting several different UI components to call the same method when they are changed. Can you hook them up to different methods and so not need to do an `if(...)... else...`?

Comment: You could also use a switch statement and not bother declaring your elements but just declare and set them in their scopes as they are never used outside of their scopes...

Comment: `as` and test for `null` is another way. `var cb = sender as ComboBox`, `if (cb != null) f = cb.SelectedIndex;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `as` instead of `typeof`:

```
  ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
  ToolStripComboBox tscb = sender as ToolStripComboBox;

  if (cb != null) 
    setFiltro(cb.SelectedIndex);
  else if (tscb != null)
    setFiltro(tscb.SelectedIndex);
  else
    setFiltro(-1);
```

or exploit *Reflection*:

```
  PropertyInfo pi = sender.GetType().GetProperty("SelectedIndex");

  // You can add some additional checks here:
  // pi is int property
  // pi has get accessor as well as set one

  if (pi != null)
    setFiltro((int) (pi.GetValue(sender))); 
  else
    setFiltro(-1);
```